# Standard Practice to create PopUp form which then updates parent form dropdown without Parent page refresh?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3, C#, Razor, EF4.1, SQLServer 2008.

I have a parent form with a dropdown for "Suppliers". I wish to add a "quick add" link/button that enables the user to quickly add a supplier to the DB which is then available in the dropdown for selection. At present this is achieved by

```
Parent Page -> Add Supplier Page -> Parent Page(Page Refresh)
```

Of course on return to the parent page, it refreshes and removes all non saved data - which is a problem. It would be better to have a popup window which then saves the suppliers and then just refreshes the dropdown portion of the parent page form. So I believe I am seeking an approach to:

```
Parent Page -> Popup(Modal) -> DB Save -> Refresh DropDown in Parent Page (Ajax???) -> close Modal popup.
```

I would appreciate guidance on the above, as I am a little stuck on the best practice and hopefully simple approach to this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally do something like this:

Create an 'Add' button that will display a popup. (I use jQuery dialogs. They are simple, free, and easily to implement by just calling .dialog on a `div`). Inside this dialog have the appropriate fields needed to create a new supplier. Have a 'Save' button in this dialog and have it wired up to a `AJAX` post. (Again this is very simple using jQuery)

If you do use jQuery its as simple as submitting that form to your controller action that will then call you data access layer to save the new supplier entity. When the `AJAX` call comes back successfully you can reload the contents of the supplier grid with another `AJAX` post. All the 'Magic' comes from implementing `AJAX` really which will allow for you to retain the users input and not reload the whole page. The `AJAX` call that is executed after the user enters in a new Supplier and clicks save would look something like this:

In your JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ControllerName/SaveNewSupplier",
    Data: $('#YourAddNewSupplierFormName').serialize(),
    Type: "POST"
    Success: function(result) {
    // this is what will get called after a successful save and return of your action method on your controller. This is where you will put the call to repopulate the supplier list with the updated list.
      UpdateSupplierList(); // This function is created below
}
});
```

In your controller:

```
Public JsonResult SaveNewSupplier (NewSupplierModel newSupplier)
{
 // save your new supplier through your data access layer
// if save is successful then return
Return Json({success = true}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}
```

Then to repopulate the initial div that contains all the suppliers do something like this:

In JavaScript:

```
function UpdateSupplierList()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "ControllerName/GetAllSuppliers",
        Type: "GET"
        Success: function(result) {
        $('#SuppliersDiv').html(result.suppliers)
}
```

And in your controller:

```
// remember that a lot of this is pseudo code and your will have to implement it better for your situation. But basically its just:

Public JsonResult GetAllSuppliers()
{
  var suppliers = db.GetSuppliers()
  return Jason({suppliers = suppliers}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

EDIT: If you are updating a SelectList via jQuery then this article is almost identical to what I explained but goes into much more detail on updating the select list. Hope this helps. 
http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/23/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-using-jquery-and-ajax/

Comment: Thank you so much for this. In my case I am using a dropdown that needs repopulating. Could you elaborate a little on how the GetAllSuppliers would be called to populate this dropdown please. Many thanks again.

Comment: Are you using a SelectList for populating your Dropdown?

Comment: Yes I guess I am ie <Select><Option>..... via the razor HTML.DropDownListFor helper method.

Comment: Check out the last edit I made to this answer. I believe the link I posted is exactly what you want to do. And it really is how you should be doing it if you are trying to do it the correct way. Good Luck!